# Pull items by language

Tags: sitecore-cli, scs

I'm using the command `dotnet sitecore ser pull`.

The Source system has items with "Invariant Language" listed. It has no versions though. So, when pulling the items using CLI, it only creates folders and no yaml because of that error.

So, wanted to check, is it possible to get the serialized items for only `en`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not. Serializing an item that has no versions should still be possible however, you should bring this to Sitecore Support.

All current options available to you can be found in the [Sitecore Content Serialization configuration reference](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/101/developer-tools/en/sitecore-content-serialization-configuration-reference.html).

As of today, filtering of any kind is not possible.